# Objective-C protocol static method?

Tags: objective-c, static, protocols

I have a protocol in Objective-C, something like this:

```
@protocol Handler
+(NSString*) getValue;
@end
```

So now say I have an instance that inherits this protocol and I want to call this method:

```
[handlerInstance getValue];
```

This gives a warning because the `getValue` method is not an instance method. How can I properly call this method from my instance? (Without knowing the concrete class)? I'm guessing something like this, but I'm not exactly sure:

```
[[handlerInstance class] getValue];
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
[[handlerInstance class] getValue];
```

Yes, like this.

Unlike Java and C++, **class methods** can only be sent to the class.

Comment: Seriously, I guess I shouldn't have second guessed myself!

Comment: Not all of us.  Trying it out before posting doesn't give others the benefit of the knowledge.  I came here searching for how this would behave because 1.) it was quicker than trying it out and 2.) if there were pitfalls I hadn't thought of, someone would likely note them here.  Posting first is therefore less work for everyone who comes later.  Thanks Kenny and Zenox.

Comment: So if I have a variable `id<Handler> handler` do I assign `instance` or `[instance class]` ? Will this work even without an instance available? (Only a `Class`)?

Comment: @chakrit: `[[instance class] getValue]`. If you have a `Class cls`, then do `[cls getValue]`. Note that this method will not execute if `handler == nil`.

Comment: In general the point of class methods is not using an instance.